# Change Owner and Group in Public HTML

Tags: linux, file-permissions, file-ownership

I had unziped files (Wordpress) via terminal in `public_html`. But the extracted files have value ***"Zero" as group / owner*** attributes.

I want them to match my `public_html` i.e. `Owner = 704 & Group = 99`

[image: Current file permissions]

How can I rest these to a specific value? And how to do it recursively?

Comment: Code ? What have you tryed ?

Comment: i didn't do anything yet to update attributes, don't know the proper syntax

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The question better fits to unix & linux, or super user, anyway, put one question to Google and you will got the answer- hint- look for `chown` or `chmod` - chown for owner chmod for permission (read/ write/ execute)..
If you are asking how to change it on machine, if you are asking how to change it from wordpress, then its for wordpress support / forum more likely , particular answer is there https://superuser.com/questions/289300/whats-easy-way-to-change-file-permission-in-linux

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown):

```
chown [owner value][:[group value]] -R /path/to/folder
```

It changes the owner and the group of files and folders to values `owner value` and `group value`. Flag **-R** tells it to operate recursively.

Comment: this command should works as well for user / group name as well for UID , GUI (user id, group id) 
So for this case I think 
`chown 704:99 <pathTo>/public_html` If the numbers are corresponding UID and GUI.. Referring [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)